# download PDF file using angular 2 and .Net core webapi

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am trying to download PDF (and later word,excel and image) file using angular 2 with .Net core web api. I have pasted some code sample here which downloads the file but when I try to open the downloaded file, it gives me corrupted file.

Here is my .net core web api code

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetTestPdfFile()
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(myArray); //byte[] myArray is byte[] of file downloaded from Azure blob
            //response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = myFileName;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            return response;
        }
```

I have also tried another code sample

```
public FileResult TestDownload(int id)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(myArray, "application/pdf")
            {
                FileDownloadName = "test.pdf"
            };

            return result;
        }
```

This is what I have in angular service

```
getTestPdfFile(): Observable<any> {
        let url = 'API_URL'
        let headers1 = new Headers();
        headers1.append('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        headers1.append('responseType', 'arrayBuffer');

        return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers1})
            .map(res => {
                var contentType = 'application/pdf';
                var blob = new Blob([res.arrayBuffer()], { type: contentType });
                return blob;
            })
    }
```

This is how I am subscribing to obsevable

```
this.myService.getTestPdfFile()
        .subscribe(blob => {
                var link=document.createElement('a');
                link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download="Test.pdf";
                link.click();
            }, error => {});
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I had to change my angular service to below and all worked fine

```
getTestPdfFile(): Observable<any> {
        let url = 'API_URL'
        return this.http.get(url, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
                        .map(res => res.blob())
                        .catch(this.handleError)
    }
```

I am using this as my web api

```
public FileResult TestDownload(int id)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(myArray, "application/pdf")
            {
                FileDownloadName = "test.pdf"
            };

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Great! But, what if I want to open the PDF in the browser instead of downloading?

Answer (score 3):

I've never had luck downloading items using observables.  What I've done instead is use `window.open("http://urlToDocument.Test.pdf", "_blank")`. This will download or prompt to download the file in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks. I found answer as posted.

Comment: but what if you only want authenticated users to download the file?